# cut an object in 3 pieces and view them in blade - Laravel - chunk method

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an object with multiple data:

```
    $products = Products::whereIn('id', $input['product_id'])->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();
```

dd output of $products looks like that:

```
Collection {#287 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => Products {#288 ▶}
    1 => Products {#289 ▶}
    2 => Products {#290 ▶}
    3 => Products {#291 ▶}
    4 => Products {#292 ▶}
    5 => Products {#293 ▶}
    6 => Products {#294 ▶}
    7 => Products {#295 ▶}
    8 => Products {#296 ▶}
    9 => Products {#297 ▶}
    10 => Products {#298 ▶}
    11 => Products {#299 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I'm returning the object to my blade and trying to output the data on 3 columns like this:

```
    @foreach($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
            @foreach($chunk as $product)
                <div style="width: 33%">{{ $product->name }}<br></div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

But this just gives me the data among themselves

like:

```
A
B
C
D
...
```

but I need it on 3 columns

like:

```
A  E  I
B  F  J
C  G  K
D  H  L
```

Thanks for any help! And sorry for my bad english..

I've found the chunk method on:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections
```

Comment: @HL96 `chunk()` gives [A, B, C, D], [E, F, G, H], [I, J, K, L] rather than [A, E, I], [B, F, J], etc., like the question states.

Comment: there isn't any error but the products aren't get listed in 3 columns. I've tried to put an border around every div but I couldn't see it.. so I thought it doesn't work

Comment: How I get the data isn't important, I just need to get them on 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `float:left;` for the `div's`, it should produce the result you want:

```
@foreach($products as $chunk)
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
        @foreach($chunk as $product)
            <div style="width: 33%; float:left">{{ $product->name }}<br></div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 1):

With `$products->chunk($perChunk)` you split the collection in parts, equal to PHP `array_chunk()`. The first parameter doesn't mean the number of chunks, but the number of items **in the chunk**.

Your solution could be:

```
{{ $numberOfColumns = 3 }}
{{ $productsPerChunk = ceil(count($products)/$numberOfColumns) }}

<div class="row" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach($products->chunk($productsPerChunk) as $chunk)
        <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
            @foreach($chunk as $product)
                <div>{{ $product->name }}</div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```